# Android UI Testing With MVVM

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, testing, mvvm

I use MVVM architecture and Dagger 2 in my application. I have a repository that gets data from servers, and when the data is retrieved ViewModel notifies the LiveData observer, which invokes the `updateUI()` method from my Activity.

So, when I am testing which views are visible with espresso, I want to wait until the `updateUI()` gets called. I cannot mock the ViewModel easily since I am using Dagger 2 but aside from that since it is an integration test, I don't want to do it in the first place.

`Thread.sleep()` would be an awful and naive solution for this, since too little waiting time would cause the test to fail, too much of it would cause to the loss of valuable time and it also depends on the testing and network environment!

So what do we do here, what's the optimal solution to this problem?

Comment: Options include: using a tool like https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/mockwebserver to mock network responses, or to inject your networking classes so that you can replace them with your own custom mocks through the app in UI tests.

Comment: @stkent I know and have already used the mockwebserver in my unit tests, but this is an integration test. Also, I cannot mock it easily since I use dagger 2 to inject activities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With more research, I have found out that Espresso has already a solution to this problem called idling resources.

You can choose a suitable idling resource implementation from the list below to integrate it into your app.

- [CountingIdlingResource](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/espresso/idling/CountingIdlingResource.html)
- [UriIdlingResource](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/espresso/idling/net/UriIdlingResource.html)
- [IdlingThreadPoolExecutor](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/espresso/idling/concurrent/IdlingThreadPoolExecutor.html)
- [IdlingScheduledThreadPoolExecutor](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/espresso/idling/concurrent/IdlingScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html)

You can start using it in your app by adding it to your Gradle file like this:

```
def espresso_version = '3.2.0' 

androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:$espresso_version"
implementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-idling-resource:$espresso_version"
```

Note that the updated Espresso version can found at [Google's Maven Repository](https://maven.google.com/web/index.html)

[Sample from Google](https://github.com/android/testing-samples/tree/master/ui/espresso/IdlingResourceSample)

[More details on idling resources](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/espresso/idling-resource)